# Function property and prototype - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, properties, prototype

What is this?

```
en4.activity.like(c)
```

Is this a function like() of property 'activity' of object en4?

I need to re-write the function but in the **same format** and I'm confused.

Comment: what is `en4`? Is this an instance or an object (direct instance of an object)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do the job:

```
var en4 = {
    activity: {
        like: function(c) {

        }
    }
};
```

In case `en4` already exists and also has a property `activity` you'd do it like this:

```
en4.activity.like = function(c) {
    ...
};
```

If that property also doesn't exist:

```
en4.activity = {
    like: function(c) {

    }
};
```

Since you just have a single object there is most likely no need to involve prototypes at all.

Comment: If `en4` exists but has no property `activity`, does the last example still work?

Comment: Nope, in this case it would have to be created first, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function nsp() {
    this.activity = {
        like: function(a) {}
    };
}

var en4 = new nsp();

en4.activity.like(c);
```